# Dynamic resizing of images

Tags: html, css

So i have this image right here

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6gO9.png"

My problem is that whenever i resize the window the Mass Effect image doesnt resize with it.

It becomes like this

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSScp.png"

I've been trying to figure this out for a while. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
   #MassEffectSign {
        background: url(masseffect12.png) center top no-repeat;
        top: 25px; left: 750px; z-index: 2;
        padding: 250px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

My blue background

```
#bodyBorder {
background: url(navyblue.jpg) center top repeat-y;
padding: 1000px;
opacity: 0.7;
background-attachment: fixed; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use percents for the relevent values.

```
top: 25px; left: 45%;
```

This makes the amount of space between the left edge and the image relative to the window size. Play around with the value a little to center it and you should be good.

Comment: Thank You! I did not realize it was this simple

Answer (score 1):

Use img tag instead background image in CSS.

```
img {width: 100%}
```

Comment: Alternatively it's possible to apply background-size: 100% to the div he currently uses, I believe. That should fix it too. But for the sake of semantics, I would also recommend using <img> in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your positioning is absolute, so it will move independently of the scale. Put that inside a relatively positioned div and then it will work.

**For instance,**

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div id="MassEffectSign">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.